# pyodbc segfault on pyodbc.connect

Tags: python, mysql, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

bit of a noob here. im trying to create a python script to stress test SQL based databases.

ive been trying to use pyodbc to connect to the database however i ran into a segmentation fault error upon pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

```
#connects to the database
def connectToDb():
print(labels.OKBLUE + "Connecting to: " + args.ip + " at port: " + args.port)

connString = ""
connString = connString + ';DRIVER=' + args.driver
connString = connString +';SERVER=' + args.ip
if not args.port == "":
    connString = connString + ';PORT=' + args.port
connString = connString + ';UID=' + args.user
connString = connString + ';PWD=' + args.password
connString = connString + ';Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30'
if not args.database == None or not args.database == "":
    connString = connString + ";Database=" + args.database
try:
    print(connString) #for debugging
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    for arg in ex.args:
        print(labels.FAIL + arg )
    sys.exit()
```

which returns this:

```
;DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;UID=root;PWD=********;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;Database=test

Segmentation fault
```

im just trying to connect to a local mysql server, and i dont know what is causing this, any help and advice is greatly appreciated

EDIT:

debian jessie as operating system

python 3 latest

odbc latest

freetds v0.91

TDS version 4.2

-- Jort

Comment: Segmentation Faults in python happen for one of two reasons:

1)You run out of memory

2) Bug in a C module

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details such as: Operating system. Python version. pyodbc version. ODBC driver version for MySQL Connector/ODBC. (Note that FreeTDS cannot connect to MySQL; it is only for SQL Server and Sybase.)

Comment: @GordThompson  > FreeTDS cannot connect to MySQL; i did not know that, which driver should i use to connect to a mysql database. i was having enough trouble getting just this one to work, and it was the one i saw popping up the most when i was searching for answers so i just assumed it would work.

Comment: Do you really have to use an odbc connector? You could try [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) or [mysql-connector-python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) instead.

Comment: @mata raises a good point. However, if you want to use ODBC to connect to different database types (using the appropriate driver, of course) then you would need to use [MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: @GordThompson i would like to be able to to connect as many SQL based database types as possible so the tool is useful against as many databases as possible, so i thought that using odbc would be a good choice, altough might not have been the best choice for a noob. i migth switch to pymysql, however i also need to be able to connect to a ms sql database. any tips on where i can find appropriate drivers? bit of a linux noob still so beginner friedly pages are mosts welcome

Comment: @mata ill look into it, altough i would also like to be able to reach a ms sql database, should i just use multiple python libs or try and get the pyodbc to work?

Comment: *"any tips on where i can find appropriate drivers?"* - Most database vendors will point you to ODBC drivers for their products. Google can find them too, e.g., "MySQL ODBC"

Comment: Last time I had to access a ms sql server I used [pymssql](http://pymssql.org), which like the other two implements dbapi2. Usually the most relevant difference between different python dbapi2 database connectors is the used [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). All three use `pyformat`, so they should be pretty much compatible in this regard. If you need to support other DBs ODBC is probably better. Or an ORM layer like sqlalchemy which can work with many diffent db drivers.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of your problem is that you are trying to use the FreeTDS ODBC driver to access a MySQL database. FreeTDS ODBC is only for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases. The ODBC driver for connecting to a MySQL database is [MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

For what it's worth, I was able to reproduce your issue under Ubuntu 16.04 using the FreeTDS ODBC driver available from the Ubuntu repositories. After the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error, the stack trace suggests that the fault actually occurred in the FreeTDS ODBC driver itself (libtdsodbc.so).

While it can be argued that a Segmentation Fault error should "never happen", there's probably no point in trying to escalate this issue. It's a classic case of

Patient: It hurts when I do this.
Doctor: Then stop doing it.

Comment: thanks alot, seems i just  made a rookie mistake by not knowing exactly how each of the systems work, also a big thanks for pointing me to the correct driver.

Comment: The patient and doctor story makes sense. ;-D